# Is there any way to access the other power plants in the Lumiose Badlands?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Finished that portion of the game, where you clear out the power plant full of Grunts.

Can I access the other power plants in the region? It tells me the "door is shut tight".

Comment: I think there is only one, those other doors are fake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some speculation/rumor that the doors may lead to events/event pokemon that have yet to be released but for now they are just shut tight.  Game Freak and Nintendo have done stuff like this through the whole history of Pokemon but then again it may just be like the truck in R/B/Y(a big red herring)

Answer (score 1):

from what i know you can't get in even after you beat the game sadly.I know because i beat pokemon y already and it might somehow be related to Volcanion Hoopa and Diancie

Answer (score -3):

it was announced that there is going to be an event with (probably) volcanion and the power plant, the event is officially going to be called "Plant Key".

Comment: Do you have a source?

Answer (score -10):

People say that if you have a Marill you can go up to one of the doors an click A on it 15 times you can get in.

Comment: Do you have any proof?

Comment: no but I did whatch a playthrough

Comment: Does this playthrough include this part that you're talking about?  If so, you should link to that video.  If not, we're not here to talk about rumors that aren't true.